# Groovy: NumberFormatException: For input string: "-5.2"

Tags: groovy

I have this code:

```
static def parseString(String inputRow, Particle particle) {
        //input row is:
        //static final inputRow = "1 -5.2 3.8"
        def map = inputRow.split()
        particle.mass = Integer.parseInt(map[0])
        particle.x = Integer.parseInt(map[1])
        particle.y = Integer.parseInt(map[2])
}
```

This code is throwing this error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-5.2"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:582)
    at RepulsionForce.parseString(RepulsionForce.groovy:13)
    at RepulsionForceTest.string should be parsed into particles(RepulsionForceTest.groovy:27)
```

How do I avoid this exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cut down redundant lines as shown below where `particle` is a map:

```
def arr = inputRow.split()
def mass, x, y
(mass, x, y) = arr*.toDouble()
def particle = [:] << [mass: mass, x: x, y: y]
```

Missed the part where `Particle` class has been referred instead.

Comment: This is very neat. Where can I read about this line: particle << [mass: mass] << [x: x] << [y: y]

Comment: `<<` is the bitwise left shift operator, which is overloaded on Collections to append objects to a collection.

Comment: Do we know that Particle is a collection?

Comment: @MichaelEaster LOL, totally missed that part `Particle particle` in the question. Thanks. I am going to update the answer in accordance to a map.

Answer (score 2):

Whoops, figured this out... 5.2 is not an integer.

```
static def parseString(String inputRow, Particle particle) {
    def map = inputRow.split()
    particle.mass = Double.parseDouble(map[0])
    particle.x = Double.parseDouble(map[1])
    particle.y = Double.parseDouble(map[2])
}
```

Comment: For more groovyness: `map[1].toDouble()`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it... Answer within a full solution:

```
// setup
class Particle {
    def mass
    def x
    def y
}

def particle = new Particle()
def inputRow = "1 -5.2 3.8"
def fieldsByIndex = [0: "mass", 1: "x", 2: "y"]

// answer
inputRow.split().eachWithIndex { val, index ->
    def field = fieldsByIndex.get(index)
    particle."${field}" = val.toDouble()
}

// output
println "mass :  " + particle.mass
println "x :  " + particle.x
println "y :  " + particle.y
```

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**: You **Mistakenly trying to parse *Double* number to *Integer* number and it's not applicable**, not sharing the same type ( integer != double) , and not gonna work - Therefore you getting `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string` exception which explicitly inform you for the type issue.

**Solution**: Convert it to to double using `Double` Class.

```
Double.parseDouble(map[i])
```